# Trying to understand this quiz question on INSERT

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

**Why will there be 2 rows and not 1? The rollback is meant to take it back to the last COMMIT function which in this case is inputted after one INSERT**

[image]

Comment: Jay, while we're happy to help you solve database issues, this is not a site for homework and quiz help. Please show that you've done some level of research, and attempted to reproduce these scenarios in your own database before posing. Pasting an image from a quiz and asking "why" is not adequate research.

Comment: And in addition to remark by @BrendanMcCaffrey, simply relying on someone to tell you the correct answer from a practice quiz will _not_ adequately prepare you for the real cert exam.  You will _not_ see these questions on the exam.  Rather you will see other questions to test your understanding of the same concepts.  You need to use every question as an entry point to your own study to understand the principle behind the question, and _why_ a given answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

[COMMIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COMMIT.html)

> Oracle Database issues an implicit COMMIT under the following
> circumstances:
>
> - Before any syntactically valid data definition language (DDL) statement, even if the statement results in an error
> - After any data definition language (DDL) statement that completes without an error